# SwiftUI BezierPath location changes on screen rotate?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to keep my BezierPath locations and alignment to each other on a screen rotation. Here is some sample code drawing two paths. I want the second path to be drawn on top of the first path, which appears to happen when the screen rotation is sideways, but not on screen rotation vertical on my device.

Is there a way to set the positions so they will always display at the same location and alignment to each other?

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            //I would like these to keep the same location/alignment to each other
            ScaledBezier(bezierPath: .logo).stroke(lineWidth: 1.0)
            ScaledBezier(bezierPath: .logo).stroke(lineWidth: 1.0).scaleEffect(2)
        }
    }
}

//Code to draw a path
struct ScaledBezier: Shape {
    let bezierPath: UIBezierPath

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = Path(bezierPath.cgPath)

        // Figure out how much bigger we need to make our path in order for it to fill the available space without clipping.
        let multiplier = min(rect.width, rect.height)

        // Create an affine transform that uses the multiplier for both dimensions equally.
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: multiplier, y: multiplier)

        // Apply that scale and send back the result.
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}
extension UIBezierPath {
    /// The Unwrap logo as a Bezier path.
    static var logo: UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.534, y: 0.5816))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.1877, y: 0.088), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.534, y: 0.5816), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.2529, y: 0.4205))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.9728, y: 0.8259), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.4922, y: 0.4949), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1.0968, y: 0.4148))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0397, y: 0.5431), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.7118, y: 0.5248), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.3329, y: 0.7442))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6211, y: 0.0279), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.508, y: 1.1956), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1.3042, y: 0.5345))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6904, y: 0.3615), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.7282, y: 0.2481), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.6904, y: 0.3615))
        return path
    }
}
```

I tried setting the location with `.position(x: 0, y: 0)`, but the paths do not keep alignment to each other on a screen rotate.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to set the drawing transform to be a constant value rather than the screen size.

```
struct ScaledBezier: Shape {
    let bezierPath: UIBezierPath

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = Path(bezierPath.cgPath)
        
        //set to constant
        let multiplier = min(1000.0, 1000.0)
        
        //constant transform
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(multiplier, 0.0, 0.0, multiplier, 0.0, 0.0)

        // Apply that scale and send back the result.
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}
```